# Transpose range while excluding hidden columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I transpose a range while excluding hidden columns?

The transpose formula always includes hidden columns by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect hidden *rows* using `subtotal()`, but cannot detect hidden *columns* that way. To do what you ask, you need a script such as this [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions):

```
/**
* Gets the data in visible columns of rangeA1. 
*
* @param {"Sheet1!A2:D42"} rangeA1 A range reference as a text string.
* @param {Sheet1!A2:D42} refresh Optional. The same range as a true reference, to force a refresh from time to time.
* @customfunction
*/
function FilterHiddenColumns(rangeA1, refresh) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 23 May 2023
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170682/269219
  let sheet, range;
  if (rangeA1.match(/!/)) {
    range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(rangeA1);
    sheet = range.getSheet();
  } else {
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);
  }
  const values = range.getValues();
  const colStart = range.getColumn();
  let result = values.map(row => []);
  values[0].forEach((_, colIndex) => {
    if (!sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(colStart + colIndex)) {
      result = result.map((row, rowIndex) => [...row, values[rowIndex][colIndex]]);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
=transpose(FilterHiddenColumns("A1:C10", A1:C10))
```

The function may have to call [Sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#iscolumnhiddenbyusercolumnposition) many times, which takes time. The runtime limit for custom functions is 30 seconds, and the function will error out if it is exceeded. The workaround is to split the range into two or more parts, and stack the results, like this:

```
=transpose( hstack( 
  FilterHiddenColumns("Bestelltabelle!I2:EZ2"; Bestelltabelle!I2:EZ2); 
  FilterHiddenColumns("Bestelltabelle!FA2:IA2"; Bestelltabelle!FA2:IA2) 
) )
```

There is currently (May 2023) no method in the SpreadsheetApp API to retrieve all hidden columns in one go. If you would like Google to change that, star [issue 128600464](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128600464) in the issue tracker. Click the star icon ☆ in the top left-hand corner to vote for fixing the issue and get notified of status changes. Please do not post a "me too" or "+1" reply, but just click the star icon. Google prioritizes issues with the most stars.

To filter hidden *rows*, use `subtotal()` and `filter()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  isRowVisible_, lambda(t,byrow(t,lambda(r,sum(bycol(r,lambda(c,subtotal(103,c))))))), 
  transpose(filter(A1:B10, isRowVisible_(A1:B10))) 
)
```

See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info), [subtotal()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649) and [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: Thanks! I tried to apply your formula but keep getting this error: Exception: Those columns are out of bounds. (row 18).

Comment: That will happen if your sheet has columns say up to `M` and you try `FilterHiddenColumns("A1:Z", A1:Z)`. Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: I checked but this is not the case. Take this example sheet where the applied formula can be found in Produktliste > A2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_4DlrHWieUjEx97PeqSEGsJhOpyutpZ8KmmStK2Vhzs/edit#gid=719339443

Comment: Thanks. Your formula does not refer to the 'Bestelltabelle' sheet as it should, but to the 'Produktliste' sheet. There aren't that many columns in the 'Produktliste' sheet so you get an error. Edited the answer to add a workable formula together with new version of the function and a workaround to deal with timeouts when there is a large number of columns.

Comment: This is great, thanks!